# Remove Pragma: no-cache from header using Action filter in Asp.net MVC core

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, http-headers, arr

I am trying to remove Pragma:no-cache from header using C# action filter but not get any luck.

I have used ARR on my website for disk cache. But my website have some pages are not required to disk cache.

For that I need to remove Pragma or any other cache control from header.
So that pages are not include into disk cache.

I have tried below code

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
        // here condition of my action method and controller name
       HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Pragma", "no-cache");
                       //OR
       HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("Pragma", "no-cache");   

  }
```

But still my action method contain Pragma

If I update into web.config file for remove/update header value than it's remove from all website method.

So if possible to remove that form Action filter than it's good for us.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Middleware` - you should be able to adapt the code below into a `Filter` of some kind too, although I haven't tried that.

Basically, as @AliBahrami says you can't change the headers once the response starts - so you need to supply a func to be be called by the framework which will do that for you - `Response.OnStarting` in the example below:

```
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseNoCachingPolicy( this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder )
        {
            return applicationBuilder.Use( async (context, next) => {
                    if(/*this request is one I don't want to cache*/)
                    {
                        context
                                .Response
                                .OnStarting( state => {
                                                var responseContext = (HttpContext)state;
                                                //remove the header you don't want in the `responseContext`
                                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                                     }, context );
                    }

                    await next();
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure how I use this into action filter. But can you pleas let me know how I get action name and controller name into your if condition?
And it's Extension? or any thing else?

Comment: Because `IApplicationBuilder` not use into action filter. It's into startup file

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara you can look at `context.Request.Path` to see if it matches your action and yes this is an extension method on `IApplicationBuilder` so you can create a static class for it then call `app.UseNoCachingPolicy()` in `StartUp`. I don't know how to put it in a filter either, I did say that in my answer -> but it shows how to do what you need.

Comment: My site url is SEO friendly  might be `context.Request.Path` not working for getting controller name and action name.